# How to make an iff statement detect any text in a text box

Tags: javascript

```
" if ((Dead == true) && (Action == "**")) { "
```

Above is my line of code. And basically what i want is for the if statement to detect ANY text in the text box defined by "Action", and then run the event if it is true.

So when a player enters anything, including an action that is already defined, it will tell the player they are dead.

i hope this makes sense,

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: You could simply use the `onchange` event and check for the input field's value with an if like this: `if(event.target.value) { ...something }`

Comment: `if(textBoxReference.value != ""){....}`

Comment: @ScottMarcus i.. didn't think of that. thanks so much!

Comment: If you want to avoid accepting just blanks, use `.value.trim()`

Comment: @ScottMarcus as i suspected, if i use a specific string that is used in another if statement, it will output the text for that specific string. is there a way to counteract this? or would i have to look at re-jigging my code?

Comment: You'll have to edit your question to make this more clear. I don't quite understand the scenario you are trying to lay out.